# drop down list in a text box

Tags: java, javascript

i want to show the details of a student who entered into the library in a text box like drop down when the mouse is placed over it

Comment: search for autocomlpete.

Answer (score 1):

Use some tooltip library, like Mootools.Tips.

Comment: +1 for not pimping jQuery ... and having an appropriate solution